# Sentinel-1 GRD and Sentinel-2 L1C on AWS bucket policy

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-1, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I started to work with Sentinel-1 data hosted on AWS S3 bucket 'sentinel-s1-l1c'. The bucket is requester pays and requires AWS signature version 4. I need to access the files via HTTP GET requests, so I generate authorization headers myself as described in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html).

When the signature expires there's an XML exception, saying that MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds equals 900 seconds. I estimate the expiration time as date in X-Amz-Date header (time of the request) + 900 seconds. But this method seems incorrect, since I have 403 Forbidden earlier than expected.

What is the correct method to calculate signature expiration time?
Should I consider [SignatureAge in bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html)? If so, then how can I get the policy? I tried to get the policy using boto3 and awscli but no success...

Since Sentinel-2 also goes requester pays, I wonder what the policy will be and how to determine the signature age when migrating code to consider Sentinel-2 bucket as requester pays?

Comment: Sentinel-2 will use the same settings since defaults are used for Requester pays. If you do not get an answer, I suggest you post this question to Sentinel Hub forum (https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/c/aws-sentinel), which is regularly monitored by Earth on AWS staff as well. (btw, Sentinel-1 L1C does not exist, it is Sentinel-1 GRD)

Comment: @GregaM., thank you. Maybe you know the date when Sentinel-2 L1C will become Requester pays?

Comment: It will take at least a few weeks more as we (our company is managing the bucket at AWS) want to make sure that access to meta-data remains easily accessible. You can monitor the thread at forum (https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/changes-of-the-access-rights-to-l1c-bucket-at-aws-public-datasets-requester-pays/172), where a firm date will be announced at least 2 weeks up front.

Comment: I am also working on the same, but with boto(python), I was able to create an HTTP URL using pre-signurl method, but when I try to access it gave me a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. is there any way I can access tiff files via HTTP?